# Revalidating Angular controls after receiving http errors in onsubmit

Tags: angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I have an angular 7 reactive form using priming controls.  When I submit a registration request, the api usermanager returns errors like "DuplicateUserName" or "DuplicateEmail".  I have validations set on the form controls which work just fine.

When I receive the errors that I can't validate via the form controls, I popup a display that shows the errors, but I would like to show the validation errors so the controls show error messages.

Here's the registration.component.ts:

```
     ngOnInit() {
        this.showModalPopup = false;

        this.email = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email/*, this.emailErrorValidator(this.email)*/]);
        this.role = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
        this.username = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]);
        this.password = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(25), Validators.minLength(6)]);
        this.cpassword = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, this.mustMatch(this.password)]);

  this.errorList = [];

        this.registerForm = this.fb.group(
          {
            'email': this.email,
            'role': this.role,
            'username': this.username,
            'password': this.password,
            'cpassword': this.cpassword

          });
      }

      onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;

        this.regUserNameError = false;
        this.regEmailError = false;
        this.registrationErrorMessages = [];

        if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
          return;
        }

        let userDetails = this.registerForm.value;

        this.acct.register(userDetails.username, userDetails.password, userDetails.email)
          .subscribe(result => {
            console.log(result);
            this.registrationErrorMessages[0] = "Your Registration Was Successful - please check your email for an email from us and click the link to verify your email address.";
            this.errorList = [];
          },
            error => {
              var i = 0;
              throwError(this.errorHandler(error));
            },
            () => {
              this.handleComplete()
              {
                console.log(this.registrationErrorMessages);
              };
            }
          );
      }

      errorHandler(error: any): void {
        console.log(error)
        var i = -1;
        for (var err of error.error.errors) {
          i++;
          this.registrationErrorMessages.push(String.fromCharCode(149) + " " + err.description);

        }

        if (this.registrationErrorMessages.length > 0) {
          this.showModalPopup = true;
        }
      }
```

In my test i registered with my information and then registered again using the same information.  It returns "DuplicateUserName" and "DuplicateEmail" as errors.  The modal popup displays the errors just fine.  How can I show the User name and Email control error messages? I have tried the following in the error handler:

```
errorHandler(error: any): void {
    console.log(error)
    var i = -1;
    for (var err of error.error.errors) {
      i++;
      this.registrationErrorMessages.push(String.fromCharCode(149) + " " + err.description);
      if (err.code == "InvalidUserName" || err.code == "DuplicateUserName") {
         this.registerForm.controls.userName.setValue(null);
      }
      if (err.code == "InvalidEmail" || err.code == "DuplicateEmail") {
        this.registerForm.controls.email.setValue(null)
      }
    }

    if (this.registrationErrorMessages.length > 0) {
      this.showModalPopup = true;
    }
```

Trying to set the values like this, gives me an error "cant setvalue on undefined", even though the debugger shows me the form and all controls as available.  Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after much wailing and gnashing of teeth, I decided to just make a call to the api and get the list of used usernames and emails and then build custom validators agains the list.  Seems to work well.